# CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) FLUTTER ERROR

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm a new flutter user here, so this time I have a problem when I login with API SERVICE, the login says

```
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

the error is in the use of the source as below

```
Future<void> login(BuildContext context) async {
    AppFocus.unfocus(context);
    if (loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      final LoginResponse? res = await apiRepository.login(
        LoginRequest(
          email: loginEmailController.text,
          password: loginPasswordController.text,
        ),
      );

      final SharedPreferences prefs = Get.find<SharedPreferences>();

      if (res!.accessToken.isNotEmpty) {
        prefs.setString(StorageConstants.token, res.accessToken);
        Get.toNamed(Routes.HOME);
        Get.snackbar("Berhasil", "Selamat Berhasil Login");
      } else {
        Get.snackbar("title", "coab");
      }
    }
  }
```

exactly the error appears in this section

```
if (res!.accessToken.isNotEmpty)
```

Answer (score 0):

`final LoginResponse? res`
you declare with `?` which means `res` is nullable value.

but  `if (res!.accessToken.isNotEmpty)` you use `!` which means, res is `non-null` value. thats throw error

try to remove the `!` mark.

```
if (res?.accessToken.isNotEmpty) {
  ... rest of your code
```

or add new contidion

```
if( res != null) {
  if (res!.accessToken.isNotEmpty){
  ... rest of your code
  }
}
```

hope it solve your  issue. feel free to comment if any error occurred

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and test it.

```
Future<void> login(BuildContext context) async {
    if (loginFormKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
      /*
      your API code
      */
      if (res.accessToken?.isNotEmpty ?? false) {
        /*
        if accessToken found
        */
      } else {
        /*
        if accessToken not found
        */
      }
    }
    return Future.value();
  }
```

Comment: I recommend you watch the below-mentioned video for more in-depth knowledge about this topic.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgBwnMhz5nE